# Can hydrazine be protonated twice?

Tags: acid-base

First, $\ce{N2H4}$ is a base when it reacts with water, it accepts a proton.

$$\ce{N2H4 + H2O -> N2H5+ + OH-}$$

Can I follow up the reaction with this?

$$\ce{N2H5+ + H2O -> N2H6^{2+} + OH-}$$

Comment: It's not that easy to shove in the second proton. You'll need a strong acid to do that. Water will not suffice.

Comment: What does it depend on?

Comment: Having two positive charges that close to each other would cause the second proton to be very acidic. Only a *very* weak base would resist protonation by that dication.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but only to a very small amount.

The $\mathrm pK_\mathrm a$ of the hydrazinium (2+) ion in water is $-1$ (CRC Handbook of Chemistry and Physics, Ed. D.R. Lide, CRC Press, Boca Raton, FL, 2005), so the equilibrium

$$\ce{N2H5+ + H2O <<=> N2H6^2+ + OH-}$$

is almost completely on the left side.

Comment: It is the difference in $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$s of the two acids that determines the equilibrium position. You can't know where it lies just by knowing one of the values.

Answer (score 3):

Chemical suppliers sell [hydrazinium sulfate](http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/mm/104603) or $\ce{N2H6^2+\,SO4^2-}$. So yes, you *can* protonate it twice; however, as the other answer mentions you need a strong acid. Sulfuric acid is strong enough as can be seen.

Comment: Probably it isomerizes to $\ce{N2H5+HSO4-} $ in water.  Crystal lattice energetics may serve to stabilize the dicationic form in the solid state.

Answer (score 0):

when one proton is gained by hydrazine the l.p of other nitrogen will not be avialable due to the strong en value of $\ce{NH3^+}$. So biprotonated hydrazine is rare. We can get it by using strong acid.